# is AS3 AIR suitable for database applications? is SQL in AS3 as fast as SQL in C#? WPF vs FLASH

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, actionscript-3, air

I really don't know what my question's title should be and i don't know how to explain my problem, but i think if you consider reading the rest,you will figure out my problem and i will be very grateful if you could help me.

I have build applications using both langauges (C# in Visual Studio 2010 and Actionscript 3.0 AIR in Flash Professional CS6).

I have made a desktop application for an institute using AIR,
the application saves,modifies,deletes,retrieves and generates reports (i don't know what these applications are called but i think they are called Database Applications).

I use an XML file for storing information (my applications database) and use basic XML queries like:-

```
  xml.students.(name == NAME).payments //getting the payment-list of a student
```

and my own algorithms to modify and generate reports.
for example, this code displays all students' general info :-

```
  var newData:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
  for(var i:Number = 0;i < xml.student.length();i++)
  {
    newData.addItem({"Name":xml.student[i].name,"Gender":xml.student[i].gender}); 
  }
  
  /*
  i have reduced the code above to add only the students' name and gender
  otherwise the complete code would add all the students' general info to
  the variable 'newData'.
  for those who are not familiar with AS 3.0,this code will make an object
  that contains the students' name and gender,then add that object to
  the variable 'newData' which is connected to a datagrid.
  here is a porrtion of my XML file (database):-
  */
    <data>
      <student>
         <name>Raman Ubeyt Ahmet</name>
         <instrument>Tar</instrument>
         <gender>Male</gender>
         <teacher>Rasti</teacher>
         <shift>4:00 - 5:00</shift>
           <payment>
              <pay>
                <date>2013\7\12</date>
                <fee>50000</fee>
              </pay>
           </payment>
      </student>
   </data>
/*
the actual XMl file would contains 200+ students, each with a large 
and growing number of payment data '<pay><date>...</pay>'.
another report that my program generates shows all students' info, plus each
student's last payment which i think XML can not handle.
*/
```

a while later, i learned that XML is not a database and is not effecient to be a databbase. my application works properly now, but i think in the future when there is
200+ students,which i think is a large amount of data that can not be retrieved and modified quickly using XML and my algorithms,the program will slow down and might throw exceptions.

i am thinking of using SQL but i don't know whether SQL in AIR is as powerful as in C# (because C# is designed for business applications and it has LINQ to SQL) or not, if SQL in AIR is as powerful as in C#, then i will modify my program so that it uses SQL, otherwsie i will use WPF, but i also don't know whether i can design the same interface in WPF or not.
if you think that this program wil work fine and XML can handle it, then please tell me!
and here are the questions in my mind :-

am i able to design the interface i designed by Flash in WPF?
    if i used SQL in AIR, will it work as if it was made with C#?
    is actionscript 3.0 AIR suitable for business applications or i should recreate my

program in C#?
thank you again and sorry for keeping you until here.
i will be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: I didn't use Flash at all, but as far as I know, WPF (actually Silverlight which is quite the same) was designed as an alternative to Flash. So whatever you've done in Flash, you'll be able to do it in WPF. It could be a little more work though.

Comment: `am i able to design the interface i designed by Flash in WPF?` - There's NOTHING you can't do in WPF. [Here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) is an example of what can be achieved with WPF, I have not seen any air/flash/whatever random technology applications like that.

Comment: As you may or may not know, SQL is not natively supported in AS3. But SQLite is.
This being said, 200 + realy is NOT a big number of datas to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relational storage won't be slower depending on the consumer platform.

What makes sense is:

- The data access strategy.
- Cache or not cache data.
- Writing efficient queries.
- Properly handling database connections.
- ...

In the other hand, WPF is a Windows-only desktop-oriented applications UI framework. It's great and far superior compared to something like Adobe Air, but it's not cross-platform.

Microsoft's answer to Adobe Air is Silverlight, but it's almost a dead technology.

> is actionscript 3.0 AIR suitable for business applications or i should
>   recreate my program in C#?

This is very subjective. It depends on you and your actual goals. There're many WPF/Silverlight/Windows Forms business applications, and also ones made on top of Air.

It's not the tool. It's about who uses the tool. And it's also about the audience of your application, what are your goals...

The best answer for you is *just do a tech analysis about your business requirements and match which of your requirements are solved best in some of your favourite development platforms*.